# add outline to mapbox donutSegment cluster svg

Tags: javascript, svg, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have based my code from mapbox to create a cluster svg that is segmented into sections https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/

I want the cluster to have a white outline of width STROKE_WIDTH. I am trying to do this by adding another white circle underneath the cluster that is slightly larger. However, to do this I have to adjust the cx and cy of that circle so it's properly centered in the svg. But I don't know how to adjust the cx and cy of the donutSegments because I don't fully understand mapbox's code. If you know how to shift that svg or have another suggestion of how to add a white outline I would appreciate it.

This is the result I have right now:[off_center_cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtTZg.png)

Here is my simplified code:

```js
export function createDonutChart(props: Record<string, number>) {
  // code for creating an SVG donut chart from feature properties
  const offsets: number[] = [];
  const counts = Object.entries(props);

  let total = 0;
  for (const [, count] of counts) {
    offsets.push(total);
    if (count) {
      total += count;
    }
  }
  const fontSize = 16;
  const r = 18;
  const stroke_r = r + STROKE_WIDTH;
  const r0 = Math.round(r * 0.6);
  const w = stroke_r * 2;

  return (
    <div>
      <svg
        width={w}
        height={w}
        viewBox={`0 0 ${w} ${w} `}
        textAnchor="middle"
        style={{ font: `${fontSize}px sans-serif`, display: 'block' }}
      >
        <circle cx={stroke_r} cy={stroke_r} r={stroke_r} fill="white" />
        {counts.map(([color, count], i) =>
          donutSegment(offsets[i] / total, (offsets[i] + (count ?? 0)) / total, r, r0, color),
        )}
        <text dominantBaseline="central" transform={`translate(${stroke_r}, ${stroke_r})`}>
          {total.toLocaleString()}
        </text>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}

function donutSegment(start: number, end: number, r: number, r0: number, color: string) {
  if (end - start === 1) end -= 0.00001;
  const a0 = 2 * Math.PI * (start - 0.25);
  const a1 = 2 * Math.PI * (end - 0.25);
  const x0 = Math.cos(a0),
    y0 = Math.sin(a0);
  const x1 = Math.cos(a1),
    y1 = Math.sin(a1);
  const largeArc = end - start > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;

  return (
    <path
      d={`M ${r + r0 * x0} ${r + r0 * y0} L ${r + r * x0} ${r + r * y0} A ${r} ${r} 0 ${largeArc} 1 ${r + r * x1} ${
        r + r * y1
      } L ${r + r0 * x1} ${r + r0 * y1} A ${r0} ${r0} 0 ${largeArc} 0 ${r + r0 * x0} ${r + r0 * y0}`}
      fill={`${color}`}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out! The best approach is to not recenter the cx and cy of the larger circle with `stroke_r`, but instead, keep the centers the same at "r" and just have the width use `stroke_r` and shift the viewBox position to:

```
viewBox={`${-STROKE_WIDTH} ${-STROKE_WIDTH} ${w} ${w} `}
```